# Using rhc snapshot-save Returns Empty File

Tags: wordpress, openshift, remote-backup, openshift-client-tools

I have a WordPress site on OpenShift and I'm attempting to backup the site.  I've used commands:

`rhc tidy-app`

and

`rhc snapshot-save`

After reporting a snapshot is being pulled down, "Success" is displayed a few seconds later but only an empty tar.gz file is created (it's supposed to be about ~50mb).

This incident occurred before and usually, after a few repeated attempts, eventually worked.  I've tried several times now without the backup being downloaded.

Anyone have any thoughts?  Thanks.

FYI, the gear is well below the size and file count quotas

Comment: Is this using the official openshift wordpress quickstart?

Comment: Yes, this is using the OpenShift preconfigured WordPress cartridge.

Comment: I am not able to duplicate your issue.  I installed WordPress using that cartridge and ran rhc snapshot-save without issues.  When I do the tar -xvzf wptest.tar.gz I get a folder with a hash as the name (same as the applications user) with lots of data in it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  I've had this issue for over four months.  Can you suggest how to troubleshoot this?  Which log would cover this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post because I was having the same issue.  I was getting empty hello.tar.gz files when running the following command:

```
rhc snapshot save -a hello
```

After some research I found that I was missing an option.  The hello.tar.gz file contained the expected contents after running the following command:

```
rhc snapshot save -a hello --deployment
```

Comment: the problem I found was my key had expired.  What worked for me was refreshing the SSH key, which OpenShift changes monthly, and reattempt the snapshot save command.